# Is it legal to have a reference member referencing another member?

Tags: c++, reference

I am working on a class where I am trying to use constant reference members, that reference other member variables, to provide public constant access to those members. Is there a legal way to do so?

The code compiles, but gives me warnings about binding reference member to temporary values. After the `resize()` call, `A` is somehow still pointing to null, although `myA` gets updated.

Below is a recreation of what I am trying to do. I think the self referencing bit is illegal and leads to the problem, but I am not sure. Any input would be much appreciated.

```
class MyClass{
    private:
    int mySize;
    double * myA;

    void resize(int inSize) {
        mySize = inSize;

        delete [] myA;

        // detection for non-positive size is not included for brevity
        myA = new double [size];
    }

    public:
    const int & size;
    const double * const & A;

    MyClass(): 
    mySize(0)   , myA(nullptr)
    size(mySize), A(myA)      {}

    // dtor is not included
};

int main(){
    MyClass myObj;

    myObj.resize(42);

    // myObj.A[1] = 0.5 // seg fault
}
```

EDIT: Michael pointed out that this problem is related to the `const` qualifiers of `A`, and I confirmed this by changing the qualifiers of `A`, with the following result:

`double * &A` -> `A` binds to `myA` correctly.

`double * const &A` -> `A` binds to `myA` correctly.

`const double * &A` -> Not compatible. Compiler error.

`const double * const &A` -> `A` binds to temporary variable.

EDIT: It seems that the better practice is to use a getter function.

Comment: Where is `size` set? I see `mySize = inSize`, but no `size =` anything. Even if it's legal, it's a rather odd construction.

Comment: And why do you have public references to your own members?

Comment: Should work, but because references can't be reseated you're losing the ability to assign the class (speaking of, familiarize yourself with the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and friends). Why not `const`-returning getter functions? They'll compile away to nothing. Also, consider using `std::vector`.  It handles all of the memory management for you (Including being Rule of Five compliant so `MyClass` can stick to the Rule of Zero).

Comment: @user4581301 I am aware of the getter functions, just wondering if this alternative approach would work. I don't think this referencing would get in the way of copy / assignment, because the class can just change the value of ```mySize```/```myA``` ...?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Basically as an alternative for ```const double * getA() const; ```. Getter functions are nice and all, but looks rather unwieldly in the code I guess.

Comment: @Emmet ```size``` is set in the initialization list.

Comment: The problem is you have to write your own assignment operator, something you need to do anyway to protect `myA`.

Comment: Comma is missing after `myA(nullptr)`. Seems it should not compile successfull...

Comment: The standard way to provide public `const` access to your private data members is via member *functions*, i.e. `int size() const { return mySize; }`. Such simple getters are typically inline and optimised away, while it is not all obvious that your references will be optimised away....

Comment: Your posted code should actually compile: avoid typos. Also, this is a **classical example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)** as the real question is why would one do this sort of nonsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types `double*` and `const double*` are incompatible, so you cannot initialize a reference to the latter from an instance of the former. However, this is not illegal, but the compiler instead generates a temporary to bind to the reference (leading to a dangling reference -- IMHO, this should not be allowed, i.e. be an error).

If your intention was to provide `public` `const` access to your `private` data, then the standard method is to use member functions:

```
int size() const noexcept { return mySize; }
const double* A() const noexcept { return myA; }
```

which will be optimized by the compiler.

Another way to make your code work is to add another private member:

```
double*myA;
const double*myAconst;

const double* const& A = myAconst;
```

and ensure that `myA` and `myAconst` always point to the same address. You may also avoid `myA` in favour of `myAconst` and use `const_cast<double*>(myAconst)` if you need to modify the elements allocated (this is a legal use of `const_cast<>`, since the address points to genuine non-constant data.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the initialization `A(myA)` is that `A` is of type `const double * const &` while `myA` is of type `double *`. The type that `A` refers to is not [reference-compatible](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4) with the type of `myA` (thanks to @guest for clarifying this). As a result, the reference `A` will be bound to a temporary object materialized from the prvalue that is the result of implicitly converting `myA` to `const double * const` [[dcl.init.ref]/5.4.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.4.2). However, the lifetime of the temporary will not be extended [[class.temporary]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#5) and, thus, the temporary will be destroyed right after the initialization takes place, leaving `A` [dangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). That's what the compiler warns you about here.

There is nothing illegal about having references to your own members. The question is: What's the point of doing it? While references are not objects themselves and it is unspecified whether they take storage or not [[dcl.ref]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#4), compilers will typically implement reference member variables by introducing fields that hold the addresses of the objects the reference refers to (in other words: references will compile down to basically pointers). As a result, half the memory used by an object of type `MyClass` in your example above will be used for storing addresses that point into the object in which the addresses themselves are stored. Knowing where to find one of these addresses requires already knowing where the thing they are pointing to is…So it's not illegal, but it's probably not such a great thing to do…

Comment: Thanks for finding those quotes. Saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: Same or very similar bug in GCC 8 then. GCC emitted a warning but compiled and the program printed the wrong address fro the reference.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Thank you for the answer! Tested on gcc5.4, seems to compile perfectly.

Comment: @YifanLai note that it may be wrong, I'll have to check more thoroughly, will update as soon as I know more…

Comment: The problem is `const double *`, yes. Only top-level qualifiers may differ for direct binding.

Comment: @YifanLai note that I was indeed wrong to change my answer (I got confused there unfortunately) and my initial answer was mostly correct. I reverted my answer, please see above and also consider the answer by Walter that has been added in the meanwhile…

Comment: @YifanLai since I, unfortunately, tricked myself into thinking that my initial answer was wrong, which led to my answer being left here in an incorrect state for a while until I rolled it back and improved it now, I recommend that you accept the correct answer that Walter provided in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Michael Kenzel By the "early C++ draft", which you refer to, there should be direct binding. But it seems too early... :-)